# Rx Observable Sample operator that emits values at the beginning rather than the end of the period

Tags: c#, system.reactive

RxJs includes the handy [throttleTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttleTime) operator that unlike .NET's [Throttle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229400(v=vs.103)) operator can be configured to emit values from the source sequence at the beginning of the interval, rather than the end. Am I missing something or do I have to roll my own implementation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather simple to roll your own.

Try this:

```
source
    .Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    .SelectMany(xs => xs.Take(1));
```